# What is the difference between Promiscuous and Monitor Mode in Wireless Networks?

Tags: sniffer, wireless

In Wireless Networks, you can put your wireless card in Promiscuous or in Monitor Mode.

What is the difference between these two modes ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

- **[Monitor mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode):** Sniffing the packets in the air without connecting (associating) with any access point.

  Think of it like listening to people's conversations while you walk down the street.
- **[Promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode):** Sniffing the packets after connecting to an access point. This is possible because the wireless-enabled devices send the data in the air but only "mark" them to be processed by the intended receiver. They cannot send the packets and make sure they only reach a specific device, unlike with switched LANs.

  Think of it like joining a group of people in a conversation, but at the same time being able to hear when someone says "Hey, Mike, I have a new laptop". Even though you're not Mike, and that sentence was intended to be heard by Mike, but you're still able to hear it.

Answer (score 22):

**Promiscuous Mode:**

Capture packets on a network that you have connected to. This is likely what you need to be in if you want to analyze packets (Wireshark, tcpdump, etc.)

**Monitor Mode:**

Capture packets regardless of connected network. No association to AP needed (and no authentication). Because it is not connected to a network, you can't process the Ethernet info.

[Link](http://lazysolutions.blogspot.ca/2008/10/difference-promiscuous-vs-monitor-mode.html)