# Sniff network packets that don't talk to my computer?

Tags: network, wireless, sniffer, monitoring, packet

How would one sniff wireless network packets that do not pass directly through my computer- without access the the AP or router?

I want to be able to sniff for network traffic (even while encrypted) when authenticated to the network and when not authenticated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about wireless or wired? Also, you want to sniff wifi for a network you are *not* authenticated on?

Comment: @d1str0   Wireless.  And I would like to look at both, but I suppose the authenticated network would be easier at first.

Comment: You CAN capture wireless packets, but they will be useless to you unless you know they key to decrypt them.

Comment: @l1thal, I'm looking at the 'how' to do that.  I'm interested in even seeing what "useless" packets look like

Comment: Please clarify that you are talking about wireless.

Comment: Well your question asked 'is it possible'. not 'how'.

Comment: If you want to learn how to do this, I can show you. Add me on skype - l1thal. otherwise, please change your question to ask 'how' and not 'is it possible'

Comment: I remember in the past you need a certain kind of wifi transmitter capable of driving these sniffing modes, I'm not sure if this is nowa standard or not... I believe there is a way to sniff wifi internet packets via cell phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You are looking for [promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) or monitor mode.

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/37000/28585

Comment: Thanks.  So would Wireshark do the job by itself or is it necessary to use Aircrack-ng suite...assuming you're authenticated?

Comment: If only it was enough...There are so much more to it than this.

Comment: Nope, promiscuous mode won't necessarily work; you probably need monitor mode.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run in [monitor mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode); promiscuous mode doesn't always work with Wi-Fi adapters (and may not even be supported for Wi-Fi on some OSes or with some Wi-Fi adapters).

Whether Wireshark can do it by itself depends on the OS.  On OS X, it can; on Linux, it could, in theory, but for complicated reasons it can't, on most if not all distributions, in practice, so you need aircrack-ng's airmon-ng script to turn monitor mode on, and you can capture after that; on Windows, it can't do it at all except with an AirPcap adapter; on other OSes, maybe, maybe not.  See [the Wireshark Wiki's page on WLAN capturing](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Turning_on_monitor_mode) for details.