# Aircrack-ng Windows 10 with USB WiFi in Promiscuous mode

Tags: wifi, windows-10, aircrack-ng

I have seen many tutorials and lessons about how to use *aircrack-ng* suite in Linux. Can I use this suite in Windows 10? If so, from  where can I download binaries safely? (if you google, there are many binaries, but I do not want to infect my host machine with malware)

I do have a USB WiFi adapter (TL-WN722N) and can I use it in promiscuous mode in Windows with *aircrack-ng* suite? If so, how?

Comment: There used to be drivers for windows several years ago but they never got much traction and were abandoned as a result. Your best bet is to boot your machine on an Linux USB.

Comment: Why does it need to be windows?

Comment: Also, a VM would suffice

Comment: @J.A.K : Windows is the only option I have at the moment to execute this test. I am out of options here.

Comment: You can set your WIFI adaptor to monitor mode using NetMon, but I doubt that you can get aircrack-ng to run on Windows.

Comment: I see... in that case, I can perform this using Kali VM. But I doubt whether I can get the promiscuous mode from my USB WiFi adaptor ?

Comment: Why would you need promiscuous mode? I think you might mean monitor mode.http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36997/what-is-the-difference-between-promiscuous-and-monitor-mode-in-wireless-networks

Comment: I need to analyse traffic from my network's all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you’d be able to get aircrack-ng to work on Windows. You’d also have to install the drivers. I recommend installing Virtual Box and getting the Kali Linux iso. Aircrack-ng comes preinstalled in it, all you have to do then is purchase a monitor mode supported WiFi adapter card. I suggest an ALFA one, I have one and it works perfectly. After that it’s really just a matter of opening up settings in virtual box and adding the WiFi adapter as a usb device. You should be able to use aircrack-ng then! There tons of tutorials on YouTube on how to install Kali Linux and connect a WiFi adapter.